# Python 3 removing puctuation from text file

Tags: python

I'm a beginning programmer and I've been having some trouble with my assignment. So i'm hoping you will be able to help me with it. My assignment is as follows:

Write a program in Python that displays on the  screen the last 3  words of lines read from a text file entered as standard input. Assume that all lines in the text file contain at least three words. Consider as a word only a string of at least one letter.

This is the input text file:

```
Elizabeth it is in vain you say
"Love not"â€”thou sayest it in so sweet a way:
In vain those words from thee or L.E.L.
Zantippe's talents had enforced so well:
Ah! if that language from thy heart arise,
Breath it less gently forthâ€”and veil thine eyes.
Endymion, recollect, when Luna tried
To cure his loveâ€”was cured of all besideâ€”
His follieâ€”prideâ€”and passionâ€”for he died.
```

and this should be the output:

```
vain you say 
sweet a way 
l e l 
enforced so well 
thy heart arise 
veil thine eyes 
when luna tried 
of all beside 
for he died
```

However, it seems I'm required to remove all punctuation as well. And this is what i'm having trouble with. So here's my code:

```
import sys

def main():

    for item in sys.stdin:
        item = item.split()[-3:]
        string = ' '.join(item)
        print (string)

main()
```

Comment: What have you tried to remove punctuation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is `s.translate(None, string.punctuation)`

Comment: If you need an alternative I would be happy to provide one but none will beat what I have put in terms of efficiency